# how to restrict user not to enter more than ten character name?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

Could you please tell me how to restrict user not to enter ten  character in name field? If user enter more than 10 character than he will not able to enter that. Please suggest a better way?

http://plnkr.co/edit/w1cidR23RYLAYE6dlvXd?p=preview
I have a name field in which user only enter ten digit name not more than that. If the user try to enter more it not allow.

```
<td ng-if="value.type == 'FIELD' && isEditableMode && value.editable && value.dataType!='DATE'">
  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': myform[key].$invalid}">
    <input type="text" name="{{key}}" class="form-control" ng-model="value.value">
  </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply set the [`maxlength`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/maxlength) attribute.

> The `maxlength` attribute specifies the maximum number of characters allowed in the *input* element.

**Demo:**

```html
<input maxlength="10" type="text"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 attributes that allow you to add a minimum and maximum to your input they are **min** and **max**

so just add max ="10" into your input tag

Comment: Another solution:
set $scope.name=10 in controller, then add max="{{name}}" into your tag